# react-native-paytm gives black screen on IOS

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I have integrated react-native-paytm from [here](https://github.com/tejashwikalptaru/react-native-paytm) 
,and now after calling the `paytm.startPayment(details);`
makes the screen black on iOS for some times and then the app crashes.

```
runTransaction(paytmObj) {
        const details = {
            mode: 'Staging', // 'Staging' or 'Production'
            mid: paytmObj.MID,
            industryType: paytmObj.INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID,
            website: paytmObj.WEBSITE,
            channel: paytmObj.CHANNEL_ID,
            amount: paytmObj.TXN_AMOUNT, // String
            orderId: paytmObj.ORDER_ID, // String
            custId: paytmObj.CUST_ID, // String
            checksumhash: paytmObj.CHECKSUMHASH, //From your server using PayTM Checksum Utility 
            callback: paytmObj.CALLBACK_URL
        };
        console.log('PAYTM Details : ',details);
        paytm.startPayment(details);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed in this fork: [@philly25/react-native-paytm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@philly25/react-native-paytm)

It also supports latest React Native.